# How to find IP subnet that is decomposed into multiple sub-one?

Tags: optimization, mysql-8.0

I have a table which like like that:

| Id | IpRange | Mask |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 127.0.0.0 | 24 |
| 2 | 127.0.1.0 | 24 |
| 3 | 127.0.2.0 | 24 |

I'm checking if an IP is in the range thanks to this :

```sql
(inet_aton('here is the IP') & ((POWER(2,32)-1)<<(32-Mask)) & (POWER(2,32)-1)) = inet_aton(IpRange)
```

But now, I'm getting lot of IP ranges. I want to optimize them. In the case given, I want this:

| Id | IpRange | Mask |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 127.0.0.0 | 23 |
| 3 | 127.0.2.0 | 24 |

As [`127.0.0.0/24`](https://www.adminsub.net/ipv4-subnet-calculator/127.0.0.0/24) + [`127.0.1.0/24`](https://www.adminsub.net/ipv4-subnet-calculator/127.0.1.0/24) = [`127.0.0.0/23`](https://www.adminsub.net/ipv4-subnet-calculator/127.0.1.0/23).

Actually, I made this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Ips WHERE (-1 << (33 - Mask)) & INET_ATON(IpRange) = INET_ATON("127.0.0.0")
```

That check if for this specific example, and well found both line for the given super-subnet.

I made a [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vnrcayyu4R9AH51pYQb427/0).

Is there a way to do it without check for each subnet, and without counting one by one it contains all subnet?

Comment: Simply convert your subnets from IP-mask to from-till. I.e. (127.0.0.0, 24) -> (127.0.0.0, 127.0.0.255). And your problem will transform to common WHERE BETWEEN.

Comment: @Akina that's a good idea yes. To transform it to x.x.x.255 seems pretty easy, but make it back as x.x.x.0/24 seems hard :/

Comment: ?? `32 - LOG2(INET_ATON(ip_from) ^ INET_ATON(ip_till) + 1)`

Comment: Oh, ok thanks, i'll try to do something and -maybe- make an answer if I found